# Full calendar filtering

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar

My view code where full calendar is displayed is below:

```
<div class="content">
    <div id='input'>
        <?php echo form_dropdown("package_id", $packagelist, "",'id="packageid"'); ?>
    </div>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
</div>

<style>
    #calendar {
        max-width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#packageid').change(function() { //any select change on the dropdown with id country trigger this code           
         //$('#calendar').fullCalendar ('removeEvents');   
        var packageid = $('#packageid').val();
            alert(packageid);
            if(packageid !== null)
            { $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                 //var $pid = packageid;
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
                },
                displayEventEnd: {
                    month: true,
                    basicWeek: true,
                    "default": true
                },
                defaultDate: '2014-11-12',
                //editable: true,
                eventLimit: false, // allow "more" link when too many events

                events: 
                "<?php echo base_url('admin/schedule/scheduledetails/hel/');?>"+"/"+packageid,
            }); 
    }


        });
    });

</script>
```

When i click the dropdown selection for the first time , then the filtered events is displayed on calendar. But when i click another item on the dropdown menu then no change occurs on the calendar. Now if i refresh the page and select another item from dropdown, then the calendar with filtered events is displayed. Now again if i try to change the dropdown selection, no change occurs on the calendar. What am i doing wrong. I have called the javascript to display the calendar after the onchange function.

EDIT 2: Now I have edited my code to something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function(e)  {  
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
                },
                displayEventEnd: {
                    month: true,
                    basicWeek: true,
                    "default": true
                },
                defaultDate: '2015-11-12',
                //editable: true,
                eventLimit: false, // allow "more" link when too many events

                events: "<?php echo base_url('admin/schedule/scheduledetails/json/')?>",
                 cache : false,
            }); 

});


</script>
```

this script is for displaying the calendar initially with the overall events.

Now the following script is done for filtering the events:

```
<script>

     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#packageid').change(function() { //any select change on the dropdown with id country trigger this code           
         $('#calendar').fullCalendar ('removeEvents');   
        var packageid = $('#packageid').val();
           // alert(packageid);
             $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');

             $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', '<?php echo base_url();?>admin/schedule/scheduledetails/hel/'+packageid); 
             //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');

        }); 
    });


</script>
```

The problem that is occuring is that . The calendar is initially loaded with the whole data. And when i click the dropdown button for filtering , the filtering ocurs. If i click the prev or next button on full calendar , then also it works without event being duplicated.
Now if i select the next event from the database, again the filtering occurs perfectly. But when i click the previous or next button , the events of previous dropdown selection plus the present dropdown selection is displayed on the fullcalendar view. Why is it happening? I have used removeEvents . Why isnot it working?

Answer (score 0):

Your calling fullCalendar to create the calendar new each time,  you need to destroy it, or just change the source and refresh:

what i do here is add a new source; if you want to change/remove the old source you can do that, just save the event source in a variable to be used in the 'removeEventSource' call before the 'addEventSource' call.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
                },
                displayEventEnd: {
                    month: true,
                    basicWeek: true,
                    "default": true
                },
                defaultDate: '2014-11-12',
                //editable: true,
                eventLimit: false, // allow "more" link when too many events

                events: 
                "<?php echo base_url('admin/schedule/scheduledetails/hel/');?>"+"/"+packageid,
            }); 

        $('#packageid').change(function() { //any select change on the dropdown with id country trigger this code           
        var packageid = $('#packageid').val();
            alert(packageid);
        if( packageid != null ) {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', '/admin/schedule/scheduledetails/hel/'+packageid);
        }

    }


        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: if i remove this code then it displays calendar initially. How ever the dropdown functino doesnot work $('#packageid').change(function() { //any select change on the dropdown with id country trigger this code           
        var packageid = $('#packageid').val();
            alert(packageid);
        if( packageid != null ) {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', '/admin/schedule/scheduledetails/hel/'+packageid);
        }

    }


        });

Comment: have you used firebug to see if any errors are thrown, or do some console.log messages to see if values are properly set?  also, add your event data that is returned from you URL perhaps there is an issue there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to implement filtering with FullCalendar.  Event is triggered by use of a dropdown.  Initial view shows all events.  Using dropdown triggers the filters. Filters hold across month, week and day views.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        defaultDate: (new Date()).toISOString().substring(0, 10),
        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: 'include/myfeed.php'
    });

});

function filterByDealer(dealer){
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource','include/myfeed.php?d='+dealer);
}
```